# how to maintain order while doing bulk create in sequalizejs LINUX environment?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database-design, sequelize.js

I am creating database records from nodejs using sequalizejs . I am passing array of data and this is being added into the database table.
The problem is the data which is passed is not saved as it is . The order is different . Please suggest how to maintain order while doing bulk create in sequalizejs? . **The issue is seen only with LINUX environment. In Windows server , it is working fine.**

```
data - ["A","B","C","D"]
table row order - "B" , "D" , "C" , "A"
```

Every run the order varies .

```
models.MyTable.bulkCreate(req.body, { individualHooks: true }).then(function (mydata) {
        result.status(200).json(mydata);
});
```

Comment: What is the exact `SQL` generated by your code? And what operations those individual model `hooks` perform?

Comment: The SQL is same like .. INSET INTO ... hooks are not doing any specific task.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `{ individualHooks: true }` then sequalize will create multiple  SQL queries  for insert.
All this queries will run in parallel ( like `Promise.all([insertQueries]`).Most likely you use connection pool for DB connection - this mean that all your queries will run simultaneously ( limited by settings `options.pool.max` = default 5 ).
 See https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/v3/lib/model.js#L2169

If order of query is important for you, that use next

```
var mapSeries = require('bluebird').mapSeries;
mapSeries(req.body, (item) => models.MyTable.create(item))
 .then(function (mydata) {
      result.status(200).json(mydata);
 });
```

Comment: Thanks . If I remove "{ individualHooks: true }" then all the SQL INSERT statements will be in serial order?

Comment: No - it will be just one query, which insert all records.   
       But this insert your records in correct order ( what you asked about )

Comment: Great !! . I will try this and let you know !